# How can I update my network in playground other than Deploy changes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I use 0.19.0 of composer.

when I make some changes in model file,then click `Deploy changes` button.

This action didn't update the network only, and it had created a new images and startd a new docker container.Finally, my docker will have many container running.

How can I just update the current network in contanier ?

Comment: Just kill previous chaincode containers tagged as fabric-ccenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Native Fabric Deployment](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3160) was introduced in [Composer version 0.19.0](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.0) business networks are deployed, and therefore updated, as their own chaincode. This brings Composer business networks in line with how Fabric Go or nodejs chaincode is deployed and means that members of a business network have the same control over what gets deployed across all the programming models.

There is no way to update the code in an existing container; the runtime is deployed every time you update your business network. Unfortunately, as you've noticed, that does mean you'll end up with potentially large numbers of docker containers running.

Comment: Does it mean that the runtime is deployed every time with every code change?